# Cloning relationship (and its properties) to new node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is what I'd like to do:
Starting with original which might be null.

```
WITH original, duplicate, [(original)-[rel1:HAS_RELATIONSHIPS]->(nodes) | nodes] as n
UNWIND CASE WHEN size(n)=0 THEN [null] ELSE n END AS nodes
FOREACH (o IN CASE WHEN NOT nodes is null THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
   MERGE (duplicate)-[rel2:HAS_RELATIONSHIPS]->(nodes)
   SET rel2.Property=rel1.Property)
WITH duplicate, continue...
```

I essentially want to clone rel1 (that exists between original and nodes) into rel2 (that exists between duplicate and same nodes as rel1)

I have looked at some apoc but frankly find the documentation entirely lacking so I'm not even sure where to start.

```
WITH original, duplicate
match (original)-[rel:HAS_RELATIONSHIPS]->()
CALL apoc.refactor.from(rel, duplicate) YIELD input, output
WITH duplicate, continue...
```

but the match would lose duplicate

OR

```
WITH original, duplicate
CALL apoc.cypher.doIt("
        MATCH (original)-[rel1:HAS_RELATIONSHIPS]->(nodes) 
        FOREACH(o IN CASE WHEN NOT nodes IS NULL THEN [1] ELSE [] END | 
            MERGE (duplicate)-[rel2:HAS_RELATIONSHIPS]->(nodes)
            SET rel2.Property=rel1.Property)        
        RETURN count(nodes) as relsCreated",
        {duplicate:duplicate}) YIELD value as value'
WITH duplicate, continue...
```

but here the match might unbind my variables?

Seems like there should be a simpler way to do this than with apoc.

Would be most grateful for pointers. Thanks!

Comment: Can you summarize what you are trying to do, preferably in a single sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet should work for you:

```
...

OPTIONAL MATCH (original)-[r:HAS_RELATIONSHIP]->(n)
FOREACH(x IN CASE WHEN n IS NOT NULL THEN [1] END |
    MERGE (duplicate)-[r2:HAS_RELATIONSHIP]->(n)
    SET r2 = r
)

...
```

The `FOREACH` is used to avoid invoking `MERGE` when `n` is `NULL`, which would cause an error. `SET` can be used (as shown above) to copy *all* the properties from one relationship (or node) to another.

Comment: thanks! Forgot to mention I can't do optional match because original might be null... Is there no other way to do this with pattern comprehension?

Comment: If `original` is `NULL`, `OPTIONAL MATCH` will still "work". It will just result in `NULL` values for `r` and `n` as well.

Comment: My understanding was that optional match that starts on null still executes as though the variable was unbound, and you end up with a lot of matches (ie it would find all nodes in has_relationship type relationships. Now that I do small tests it looks like you are right though. Go figure. Thanks!

Comment: No. If `original` is `NULL`, the `OPTIONAL MATCH` will not match anything, and just bind `r` and `n` to `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

I will update posting when I've QAed fully, but I am going to try:

```
WITH original, duplicate, 
[(original)-[rel1:HAS_RELATIONSHIP]->(node) | node {id: id(node), Prop: rel1.Prop}] as list
UNWIND CASE WHEN size(list)=0 THEN [null] ELSE list END AS nodes
FOREACH(o IN CASE WHEN NOT nodes is NULL THEN [nodes] ELSE [] END | 
            MERGE (n {id(n): nodes.id})
            MERGE (duplicate)-[rel2:HAS_RELATIONSHIP]->(n)
            SET rel2.Prop=nodes.Prop)
```

Comment: Yes - this works. But have to use generated id as can't merge on neo4j ids.